# testing NTLM\kerberos against a public url

Tags: java, authentication, httpclient, kerberos, ntlm

I am creating an open source Java package that makes it easy to connect with HttpClient 3.1 to resources that are protected by ntlm v1/v2 and kerberos.

I need to test this tool against real world serves. are there any publicly available endpoints that are protected by ntlm or kerberos that I can get a user and password to test against?

Basically I am looking for something like http://browserspy.dk/password-ok.php
for ntlm \kerberos

Comment: This would be very handy indeed.  If no one chimes in with an answer (and I would be surprised to see one) then I will try to see if I can set something up next week if I have a few minutes z

Comment: Here is a link to the tool i created on github, ill be happy to hear feedback. github.com/DovAmir/httpclientAuthHelper